# How do i work with objects in Self-Executing Anonymous Functions?

Tags: javascript, function, module, anonymous-function, self-executing-function

Q1 - I have

```
(function (document,window) {

var shelf = window.shelf = function (foo) {

    var init = function () {
        console.log("in init" + foo);
    };

    alert("in shelf.js "+ foo + "type" + typeof init);
};
})(document, window);
```

I want to call the init function in shelf in my HTML page in the style

```
var api=shelf("1234");
api.init();
```

Or

```
shelf().init;
```

How do i get this to work?, I read on anonymous self executing functions at,

[Self-executing anonymous functions and closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14408527/self-executing-anonymous-functions-and-closures) ,

[what is self-executing anonymous function or what is this code doing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322708/what-is-self-executing-anonymous-function-or-what-is-this-code-doing) ,

[Why do you need to invoke an anonymous function on the same line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140089/how-does-an-anonymous-function-in-javascript-work?rq=1) ,

http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/

I need the document and window objects as i will be using this to add components dynamically to my html page

Q 2 - Is this the better way or should I use anything else to ensure modularity + reuse?

Comment: For further understanding modularity, I would recommend the following links (from the same book): http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript, http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modularjavascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, `init` is not available to be called externally. I believe you're looking for something like this:

```
(function (document,window) {

var shelf = window.shelf = function (foo) {

    this.init = function () {
        console.log("in init" + foo);
    };

    alert("in shelf.js "+ foo + "type" + typeof this.init);
};
})(document, window);

var api = new shelf("1234");
api.init();
```